regarding relative path not working in vs code
in react app my code is in src under my-app folder.Image is in public/assests.so I give path as
   <img src="my-app\public\assets\cat.png" alt="A cute cat" width="300" height="200"/>

to image .But it is not working in html.
In common html code also only relative path works but not full path in vs code.
how to solve it

Possible reasons include:
Not using forward slashes (Backslash are the Windows separators)
not using file protocol, example
<img src="file://C://my-app/public/assets/cat.png>
This is not a definite answer, rather a suggestion. Posting as answer as i am unable to add comment.
Feel free to delete if not useful and accept if useful.
